# How can I know, on the first page load, what the current route is, from within a directive (AngularDart)?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

How can I know, on the first page load, what the current route is, from within a directive?

Not sure if this is a bug, or I'm not configuring things correctly. I have a directive that gets a Router injected. I listen for `router.onRouteStart` events, and when I initially reload the page, a routeStart event is not fired. I do get routeStart events when I manually trigger route changes.

My directive looks like:

```dart
@NgDirective(
    selector: '[current-route]'
)
class CurrentRoute {
  Router router;
  Element element;

  CurrentRoute(this.element, this.router) {
    toggleActive();

    router.onRouteStart.listen((e) {
      toggleActive();
    });
  }

  bool isRoute() {
    print(router.activePath);
    print(router.root);
    if (router.activePath.isEmpty) return false;
    return element.attributes['current-route'] == router.activePath.first.name;
  }

  void toggleActive() {
    if (isRoute()) {
      element.classes.add('active');
    } else {
      element.classes.remove('active');
    }
  }
}
```

When I first

```dart
print(router.activePath);   // empty list
print(router.root);  // null
```

Basically, I want to set a CSS class on an element if that element matches the current route. I'm guessing a directive with a Router is the way to go, but maybe there's something better.

Comment: Maybe a better way to ask this is: how do I tell what the default route is, if I have the Router?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you need to wait for the routing to complete:

```dart
var subscription;
subscription = router.onRouteStart.listen((e) {
  subscription.cancel();
  e.completed.then((_) {
    toggleActive();
  });
});
```

Comment: Curious, why do you cancel the subscription? In my particular case, I have my directive listening for changes. I assume there's one instance of the directive for each node its attached to. Therefore, I don't need to cancel because I always want to know about changes.

Comment: AWESOME, thanks! That's it. Waiting for the route to complete is enough for the initial page load.

Comment: If you can guarantee that there's only one instance of the directive then it's OK, but otherwise it can result in a nasty memory leak.

Comment: I have multiple elements with that directive on it. And I want each element to continually listen for route events.

Comment: @pavelgj why does onRouteStart get called twice in my angular.dart program, is it by design? (I've 2 ng-view, one embedded within other)

Comment: Is this only on first load or every time?